# How to encrypt data with Hibernate to prevent accessing column values

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption

I develop a Java web service using Hibernate to connect with the DB. Users will store data that no one should access directly, even from the DB.

Is there a possibility to generate for every user a key that encrypts/decrypts data in the DB. How to share access between a group of users?

How to do it using Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for storing encrypted content in the database through Hibernate I suggest you invest some time to study [Hibernate Encryption of Database Completely Transparent to Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1487439/131929). It suggests a number of options:

- instead of a plain JDBC connection use JDBC-over-SSL (no traffic sniffing between application and database)
- rather than encrypting specific content in the database use something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt the hard drive on which the data is stored
- use custom Hibernate `UserType`s which encrypt/decrypt data on-the-fly (i.e. instead of `String` you'd use `EncryptedString`)

The reason why the first two are often superior to what you seem to attempt is this quote from the other question

> bear in mind that any solution with client-side encryption will render
>   all your db data unusable outside of the client, ie, you will not be
>   able to use nice tools like a jdbc client or MySQL query browser, etc.

However, if still want to encrypt/decrypt data on-the-fly using custom Hibernate `UserType`s I suggest to evaluate the [Jasypt Hibernate integration](http://jasypt.org/hibernate.html) which provides such types.

Comment: Admins shouldn't have access to data too (meaning can't know what exacly user storage). So my solustion is using Jasypt?

Comment: If you can bear and accept the consequences of this solution, then yes, use Jasypt (or custom `UserType`s).

Answer (score 2):

### Transparent encryption/decryption

If your database supports transparent encryption/decryption, that's probably the best thing to do.

### Jasypt

Another option is to use you can use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/), which offers a wide range of Hibernate Types to encrypt/decrypt data.

### Using a `@ColumnTransformer`

A very easy way to encrypt/decrypt an entity attribute is to use a [`@ColumnTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-hibernate/) like this:

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    read = """
        pgp_sym_decrypt(
            storage,
            current_setting('encrypt.key')
        )
        """,
    write = """
        pgp_sym_encrypt(
            ?,
            current_setting('encrypt.key')
        )
        """
)
@Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
private String storage;
```

This way, Hibernate will be able to encrypt the entity attribute when you [`persist`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/) or [`merge`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/) it and decrypt it upon fetching the entity.